# CoreBluetooth establish peripheral connection when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS app which acts as a `central` that connects to an external `peripheral` via CoreBluetooth.

After I have connected to the `peripheral`, I read and write data to it and then disconnect. Upon disconnect, I try to establish a connection once again so the next time the `peripheral` goes into `advertise` mode, the app will connect to it like so:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    // More actions here...
}
```

It works great when the app is in the `foreground` / `background`, but when `terminated`, it doesn't work at all.

I have defined the `CBCentralManager` with the `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` like so:

```
self.central = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: Application.bluetoothRestoreIdentifier])
```

I have also implemented the `willRestoreState` central delegate method:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you do in the `willRestoreState` function?

Comment: @Paulw11 getting the peripheral again from the `dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey]` and trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
        let connectedperipherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as? [CBPeripheral]
        if let peripheral = connectedperipherals?.first {
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. I think my problem is not when the app is `terminated by the system`, I think it's when the app is `terminated by the user`. Does that make any difference?